# Unused exception in java and removing an object from the map

Tags: java, exception, dictionary, zip

I had made a game in Java. Though it works fine in eclipse, when packed into jar, a problem started that the objects in the map never get destroyed. To check for any exception, I launched it from the command-line and java stated me the following exceptions.

```
C:\Users\SriHarshaCH>java -jar C:\Users\SriHarshaCH\Desktop\Treasure.jar

java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.reset(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.reset(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at com.gej.sound.WavPlayer.loadSound(WavPlayer.java:39)
        at treasure.Treasure.initResources(Treasure.java:152)
        at com.gej.core.Game.run(Game.java:117)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.reset(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.reset(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at com.gej.sound.WavPlayer.loadSound(WavPlayer.java:39)
        at treasure.Treasure.initResources(Treasure.java:154)
        at com.gej.core.Game.run(Game.java:117)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.reset(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.reset(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at com.gej.sound.WavPlayer.loadSound(WavPlayer.java:39)
        at treasure.Treasure.initResources(Treasure.java:156)
        at com.gej.core.Game.run(Game.java:117)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.reset(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.reset(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at com.gej.sound.WavPlayer.loadSound(WavPlayer.java:39)
        at treasure.Treasure.initResources(Treasure.java:158)
        at com.gej.core.Game.run(Game.java:117)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.reset(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.reset(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at com.gej.sound.WavPlayer.loadSound(WavPlayer.java:39)
        at treasure.Treasure.initResources(Treasure.java:163)
        at com.gej.core.Game.run(Game.java:117)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

But I'm not using any zip files and the wav-player also works fine in the game. The game still launches. But the objects aren't removed from the map. How could I solve this???

Here's the updateobjects method of the map where i update and remove dead objects.

```
/**
 * Updates all the objects contained in the map.
 * @param elapsedTime The time elapsed in the current frame.
 */
public static void updateObjects(long elapsedTime){
    for (int i=0; i<objects.size(); i++){
        try {
            GObject obj = objects.get(i);
            if (obj!=null){
                if (obj.isAlive()){
                    obj.superUpdate(elapsedTime);
                    obj.moveHorizontally(elapsedTime);
                    checkCollisions(obj, true, false);
                    obj.moveVertically(elapsedTime);
                    checkCollisions(obj, false, true);
                    checkCollisions(obj, false, false);
                } else {
                    // Remove the dead object
                    objects.remove(i);
                }
            } else {
                objects.remove(i);
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e){}
    }
}
```

EDIT: Game works well when the jar is extracted and launched with the code

```
java treasure.Treasure
```

It returns nothing and plays well.

Here's the loadSound method

```
/**
 * Loads a sound from a file in the jar file to play them
 * at any time. Supports loading of .wav, .au, .aiff files.
 * Also converts MIDI files on the fly
 * @param s The path of the wav file.
 * @return The sound data loaded into the WavSound object
 */
public static WavSound loadSound(String s){
    // Get an input stream
    InputStream is = WavPlayer.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(s);
    AudioInputStream audioStream;
    try {
        // Create the audio input stream and audio format
        audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(is);
        AudioFormat format = audioStream.getFormat();
        // The length of the audio file
        int length = (int)(audioStream.getFrameLength() * format.getFrameSize());
        // The array to store the samples in
        byte[] samples = new byte[length];
        // Read the samples into array to reduce disk access (fast-execution)
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(audioStream);
        dis.readFully(samples);
        // Create a sound container
        WavSound sound = new WavSound(samples, format);
        // Don't start the sound on load
        sound.setState(SoundState.STATE_STOPPED);
        // Create a new player for each sound
        new WavPlayer(sound);
        return sound;
    } catch (Exception e){
        // An error. Mustn't happen
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now re-creating the jar file fixed the problem of the exception. But the objects aren't getting destroyed.

Comment: What map? What wav-player? Where's your code? Jar files are zip files.

Comment: First of all, mindlessly swallowing exceptions is bad, mmkay? Second, you sure the exception you're seeing is related to the code you've posted? I sincerely doubt it is.

Comment: @Jeffrey The map is the class where the game is updated. And I am not dealing with reading any zip files nor I'm using the zip package

Comment: @DaveNewton The problem I'm facing is related to the map since the objects aren't get destroyed. So I think that this is the crux of the problem

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati It's possible, I suppose, but since nothing in the stack trace includes anything in your code, not as sure. Is there a sound being played when you remove an object?

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, There's a wave file which plays in a new Thread in the game looping

Comment: @Dave the line that says `treasure.Treasure.initResources` is Sri's code, I bet...

Comment: @corsiKa Sure, but that isn't the code posted, is it.

Comment: @corsiKa This method is used to load the files in the game.

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapti My bet is that you are loading resource from your jar file. That is reading from a zip file, even if it doesn't appear to be so.

Comment: @Jeffrey Yes, the resource is located at resources/music.wav in the root of the jar file. But I'm using an input stream to load from the jar file.

Answer (score 3):

What's happening is that the API you use to play the .wav file uses `mark()` and `reset()` I/O methods.  This works fine when the .wav file is a "real" file on the filesystem, but when it's in the jar file the system can no longer do `mark()` and `reset()`.  This is a pitfall of putting data into a jar file -- at runtime, there is no guarantee that the jar file resides on a filesystem. It could even be streamed across a network and have no physical presence on the system running it.

What should happen is that you copy the .wav resources into the system-defined temporary directory at program startup, where then can be "real" files, and play them from there.

Comment: But the sounds are playing even if the exceptions are thrown. Only the objects aren't removed once created

Comment: Could I catch the exceptions in the wav-player??

Comment: As I said in my answer, you should copy all the filesystem resources to the directory identified by system property `java.io.tmpdir`, at program startup, and play them from there.

Comment: I've recreated the jar file and the sounds now play well from the jar file itself. There's an error in packaging with the CRC. I've used WinRAR to fix it and now it works well. The only problem I've had is the collision detection part in which I'm using brute-force which is slowing the game down and the objects aren't removed from the map.